# "date -d" doesn't accept ISO 8601 format

Tags: bash, date

Am I doing something wrong? I can't believe `date -d` does not accept its own output when I use the [ISO 8601](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) option with seconds. I either have to remove the 'T' or the timezone to get it to work.

```
> date -Iseconds
2014-01-14T11:07:57-0800

> date -d "2014-01-14T11:07:57-0800"
date: invalid date `2014-01-14T11:07:57-0800'

> date -d "2014-01-14 11:07:57-0800" # remove the 'T'
Tue Jan 14 11:07:57 PST 2014

> date -d "2014-01-14T11:07:57" # remove the timezone
Mon Jan 13 20:07:57 PST 2014
```

My current solution is to use `date +"%Y-%m-%d %T %z"` instead of `date -Iseconds` but I just thought that was strange.

Comment: A `sed` command could remove the `T`... why translate back and forth?

Comment: The initial `date -d` format works for my version of bash `GNU bash, version 4.1.10(4)-release (i686-pc-cygwin)`. What is the output of `bash --version` for you?

Comment: The version of `bash` should be irrelevant; the better question is what version of `date` are each of you using?

Comment: @chepner, good point! I'm using `date (GNU coreutils) 8.15 Packaged by Cygwin (8.15-1)`.

Comment: Using `date` from GNU coreutils 8.13 on an Ubuntu 12.04 derivative, I can run: `date -Iseconds` and get the output
`2014-01-14T11:35:29-0800` and then run `date -d "$(date -Iseconds)"` and get `Tue Jan 14 11:35:52 PST 2014`, which is reasonable (I did some typing/thinking).  (LANG is set to `en_US.UTF-8`; LC_ALL and the  other LC_* variables) are all unset.) Current coreutils is 8.22 from 2013-12-13.

Comment: I've tried with `date (GNU coreutils) 8.4` on AWS Linux as well as `date (GNU sh-utils) 2.0` in Windows MINGW.

Comment: For more on ISO 8601 and older versions of `date`: http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/107750/how-to-parse-iso8601-dates-with-linux-date-command

Comment: @abiessu I am writing start and end datetimes in ISO 8601 format to a log file, then also needed to convert them to epoch seconds to calculate the duration. But you brought up a good point. I could also keep the variables in default date format and only convert to ISO 8601 when writing to the log. That way only 1-way conversion instead of 2-way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

GNU coreutils have only supported ISO 8601 dates as input since version 8.13 (released on 2011-09-08).

Thanks to @John1024 for the reference to
https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/107750/how-to-parse-iso8601-dates-with-linux-date-command

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps your locale is interfering with the date parsing?

Try specifying the time locale:

```
$ LC_TIME=C date -d "2014-01-14T11:07:57-0800"
Tue Jan 14 11:07:57 PST 2014
```

This works for me with GNU date 8.13.

Comment: This does not work for version 8.4; I suspect the ability to accept that input format is a later addition to `date`, rather than being strictly locale-dependent.